# How to use a figma component in another file?

Tags: figma

The Problem I am facing is, I just want to be able to reuse a library/component in other files, just a way to access components from a ui-kit or import them into a file. But it seems like I can't do this without upgrading to pro. I can't find any docs or help on this.

A practical example of what i want to do.

1. Duplicate a ui-kit from the community.
2. save a component from a ui-kit.
3. import it into a file/project i am working on so i can use it there.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do this:

1. Copy the component to another file as the other answer suggests. This would create a completely separate component, meaning that it's not connected to the old one in any way. This can be good or bad depending on your intentions.
2. A more commonly used case is when you want to attach instances in other files to one main component in the external file, not to the different local one. For that, Figma has Libraries which are available only on Professional, Education and Organization plans.

Official Figma video about libraries: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79T8Q6OBmRk

Help article: https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025508373-Publish-styles-and-components

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the main components into your new file and voila! It's that simple.